# Testing multiple words with Adobe Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Software: Adobe Acrobat XI professional

Scripting: Adobe JavaScript

Object: Match and test varying number of words on a pdf file and report to the console

I have a script which currently matches two words in a title inside a pdf file and reports back to the console. (this works for two words in a title eg ENGINEER APPROVAL)

The script needs to be modified to match a varying number of words **(between 5 and 12 words in a title separated by a space between each word).**

This script is run on multiple pdf files which can have a different number of words in the title.

```
numWords = this.getPageNumWords(0);
// number of words on page
// loop through the words on page
for (var j = 0; j < numWords-1; j++)
{ 
    // get word pair to test 
    ckWords = this.getPageNthWord(0, j) + ' ' + this.getPageNthWord(0, j + 1); 
    // test words** 

    // example of word string that needs to be searched for but not currently working

    // 
    if (ckWords == "DRAWING REVISED TO INCLUDE EXTENDED LAYOUT OF PLANT"
    {
        console.println(ckWords);
    }
}
```

The part of the script that will require modifying is **this.getPageNthWord**

If anyone can provide assistance for a way to test a varying number of words, that will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way PDF works is that what we understand as "words" can be placed on the canvas in any possible order. There is no concept of "sentence" or "phrase".

That said, you will have to use another way to connect the "words" Acrobat finds into a phrase. You would do that using the coordinates of the individual words, and then some heuristics to determine whether they fit together. In extremis, you would have to create an array of the bounding boxes of all words on the page, and then noodle through that array to find matching words.

Another approach which may work better would be using regular expressions in the search unit of the Redacting tool (or, to have more comfort, use the Redax tool by Appligent) for finding phrases. Just use the search utility, don't execute the Redaction.